# Create and update a spreadsheet with basic campaign data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I've just started experimenting with Google Adwords Scripts and Google Spreadsheet. I'm trying to pull basic campaign data from our manager account and send that data to a sheet.

I've written the following but every time I run the script, a spreadsheet is created that includes the headers/column names but not the actual data.

Where have I gone wrong?

```js
function main() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Adwords Testing');
  var report = AdWordsApp.report(
      'SELECT CampaignName, Clicks, Conversions, Cost, Ctr, AverageCpc, Impressions ' +
      'FROM   CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
      'WHERE  CampaignStatus = ENABLED ' +
      'DURING LAST_7_DAYS');

  var rows = report.rows();
  while (rows.hasNext()){
    var row = rows.next();
    var campaignName = ['CampaignName'];
    var clicks = ['Clicks'];
    var conversions = ['conversions'];
    var cost = ['Cost'];
    var avgcpc = ['AverageCpc'];
    var ctr = ['Ctr'];
    var impressions = ['Impressions'];
  }
  report.exportToSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet());
  Logger.log('your sheet is available at ' + spreadsheet);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AdWords Scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/)

> If you're interested in further scripting your AdWords accounts, take a look at AdWords Scripts, a version of *Apps Script that's embedded right into the AdWords interface*.

I think this is where your error is:

```
report.exportToSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet());
```

To add value to row you will use `getRange()`, `getValues`, and `setValues()` Classes using [`Spreadsheet Service`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

## getRange()

> Gets the range referenced by this named range.

## getValues()

> Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column. The values may be of type `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String`, depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells will be represented by an empty string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at `1, 1`, the JavaScript array will be indexed from `[0][0]`.

```
// The code below will get the values for the range C2:G8
// in the active spreadsheet. Note that this will be a javascript array.
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getValues();
Logger.log(values[0][0]);
```

## setValues()

> Sets a rectangular grid of values (must match dimensions of this range).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.
var values = [
[ "2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99" ]
];

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D2");
range.setValues(values);
```

Here is a snippet from [iluxa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156949/5995040):

```
function main() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj_Bw31w9s7LdEdLMllQMnZfbW52c3BvcTh0ekVBQ3c#gid=0").getActiveSheet();
var emptyRow = findEmptyRow(sheet);

var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000));

var range = sheet.getRange(emptyRow + 1, 1, 1, 10);

var row = range.getValues();
row[0][0] = yesterday;
row[0][1] = MONTHS[yesterday.getMonth()];
row[0][2] = DAYS_OF_WEEK[yesterday.getDay()];

var stats = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT Clicks, Impressions, Cost, Conversions " +
"FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY")
.rows()
.next();
row[0][3] = stats["Clicks"];
row[0][4] = stats["Impressions"];
row[0][7] = stats["Cost"];
row[0][8] = stats["Conversions"];
range.setValues(row);
}

function findEmptyRow(sheet) {
var dates = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 365, 1).getValues();
for (var emptyDate = 0; emptyDate < dates.length; emptyDate ++) {
if (dates[emptyDate][0].length == 0) {
return emptyDate;
}
}
}
```

Hope it helps!